# Does Java FileChannel.tryLock work on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos

I have the code that similar to below. This code works fine on Windows and Linux but on Mac 10.5 and 10.6 gives `java.io.Exception` opertaion not supported.

Many thanks for any help in this regard.

```
try
{
  File file = new File("FILELOCK3");
  FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
  FileLock lock = null;
  try
  {
    lock = channel.tryLock();
  } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e)
  {
    lock.release();
    channel.close();
    System.exit(0);
  }
} catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: [Others don't even get an exception...](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5445091)

Comment: I don't think that thread establishes that. The poster didn't show his exception handling for example, and the whole thing seems pretty dubious.

Answer (score 4):

From [another source](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev//2005/May/msg00544.html) I get the impression that the error depends on the underlying file system:

> Apple has not implemented file locking feature on a few selected file systems.

... and the referenced message was posted in May 2005.